# how to update a reactiveList with uploaded csv file

Tags: r, csv, shiny, reactive-programming

I've been struggling with Shiny reactiveValuesToList construct. The objective is to allow user-selectable lists from both pre-loaded and uploaded csv files. My thinking is that each CSV uploaded is a "named list". Each column of the csv table is the "list", with the column header as names. Then the elements of each list can be selected and used as inputs for other functions.

I guess I don't understand reactiveListToValues very well and cannot figure out how to get Shiny to reactively update the uploaded csv information.

Here is a sample CSV.

```
> read.csv("~/scratch/tmp/mydummy.csv", header=T)
   madeup1 madeup2
1      332    6836
2     9582    6184
3      983   79139
4   144455   79174
5    90701     669
6     4189   51566
7    10959    7873
8     4247    4189
9    60559     419
10    4247   13367
11    1959     787
12     447     489
13    6559     419
14     447   13367
```

The code below can be run as is. Many thanks for suggestions and help!

```
## load libraries
library(shiny)
library(stringr)

customList <- list("custom1" = c("5825","6604","55037","952","55037","55037"),
                    "custom2" = c("23386","945","11314","951","11314","51495"),
                    "custom3" = c("51495","55037","26005"))

## ShinyUI 
ui <- fluidPage(
        titlePanel("Uploading Files"),
          sidebarLayout(
            sidebarPanel(
             width =3,
             fileInput('file1', 'Choose CSV file', accept=c('txt/csv','text/comma-separated-values,text/plain','.csv')),
             tags$hr(),
             checkboxInput('header','Header', TRUE),
             radioButtons('sep','Separator', c(Comma=',',Semicolon=';',Tab='\t'), ','),
             radioButtons('quote','Quote', c(None ='',
                                             'Double Quote'='"', 
                                             'Single Quote'="'"),'"'),
             selectInput("DBname", label=h6("Select databases:"),
                         choices = c("custom" = "customList", "uploaded" = "upload_List")),
             selectInput("path_name", label=h6("Select list"),
                         choices=""),
             selectInput("elem_name", label=h6("Select element"),
                         choices="")
             ),

            mainPanel(
              column(12,
                tabsetPanel(type="tabs",
                  tabPanel("CSV File", 
                    tableOutput('contents'), verbatimTextOutput('contents2'), 
                    verbatimTextOutput('contents3')
                    )
                  )
                )
              )
           )
        )

#ShinyServer ##################################################################
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  ## under CSV tab
  output$contents <- renderTable({
    inFile <- input$file1
    if (is.null(inFile))
      return(NULL)
    read.csv(inFile$datapath, header=input$header, sep=input$sep, quote=input$quote)
  })
  output$contents2 <- renderPrint(upload_List$dList)
  output$contents3 <- renderPrint(customList)

  #____________________________________________________________________________
  upload_List <- reactiveValues()
  upload_List$fList <- c(isolate(upload_List$fList), list('same_as_custom1' = customList$custom1))

  #____________________________________________________________________________
  observe({
    inFile <- input$file1
    if (is.null(inFile)) ## need action button?
      return(NULL)
    a <- read.csv(inFile$datapath, header=input$header, sep=input$sep, quote=input$quote, colClasses="character")
    b <- lapply(a, as.character) ## break out the list and instead call by index
    upload_List$dList <- c(isolate(upload_List$dList), b[1) ## new        
    #upload_List$dList <- c(isolate(upload_List$dList), lapply(a, as.character))
  })

  #____________________________________________________________________________
## incorrect use of reactiveValueToList
  ##upload.asList <- isolate(reactiveValuesToList(upload_List))

  #____________________________________________________________________________
  DBname <- reactive(input$DBname)
  pathVar <- reactive({
    `if`(str_detect(input$DBname, "custom"), names(customList), 
         `if`(str_detect(input$DBname, "upload"), names(upload_List), ##names(upload_List$dList),
              customList$custom3 ))
  })

  #____________________________________________________________________________
  path_name <- reactive(input$path_name)
  observe({
    updateSelectInput(session, "path_name", choices = pathVar())
  })  

  #____________________________________________________________________________
  elem_name <- reactive(input$elem_name)
  observe({
    updateSelectInput(session, "elem_name", choices = elemVar())
  })

  elemVar <- reactive({
    eval(as.symbol(DBname()))[[path_name()]]
    })
}

## shinyApp
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Technically I think your problem is fixed by simply using this definition of the `elemVar` reactive:

```
  elemVar <- reactive({
   # eval(as.symbol(DBname()))[[path_name()]]
    if(str_detect(input$DBname,"custom")) return(customList[[path_name()]]) 
    if(str_detect(input$DBname,"upload")) return(upload_List$dList[[path_name()]])
  })
```

The problem of the 'Select element' choices not being updated when you select the uploaded data then goes away. You were trying to use `upload_List[[path_name()]]` to get at them, but they are stored in `upload_List$dList[[path_name()]]`

However all this code seems very complex to me, pretty sure you could write it more simply with just `reactive` functions and maybe one `reactiveValue` to store the uploaded data frame. I don't think any of the `observe` or `isolate` functions  are necessary and they confuse things significantly.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the fix! Will try to simplify the code as you've suggested. Thanks very much